# Iterating over integer[] in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, iteration, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

How can I iterate over integer[] if I have:
`operators_ids = string_to_array(operators_ids_g,',')::integer[];`
I want iterate over `operators_ids`.
I can't do it in this way:
`FOR oid IN operators_ids LOOP`
and this:
`FOR oid IN SELECT operators_ids LOOP`
`oid` is `integer`;

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over an array like

```
DO
$body$
DECLARE your_array integer[] := '{1, 2, 3}'::integer[];
BEGIN
    FOR i IN array_lower(your_array, 1) .. array_upper(your_array, 1)
    LOOP

    -- do something with your value
    raise notice '%', your_array[i];

    END LOOP;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But the main question in my view is: why do you need to do this?  There are chances you can solve your problem in better ways, for example:

```
DO
$body$
DECLARE i record;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT operators_id FROM your_table)
    LOOP

    -- do something with your value
    raise notice '%', i.operators_id;

    END LOOP;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: because operators_ids is a field which I want to use in select statement in loop: FOR oid IN SELECT operators_ids LOOP
 RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM "PRD".events_log WHERE (event_type_id = 100 OR event_type_id = 101) AND **person_id = oid** AND plc_time < begin_date_g ORDER BY plc_time DESC LIMIT 1;
END LOOP;

Comment: But I provide operators_id from function argument as text (integers separeted by comma)

Comment: Then you should redesign your schema or the ways you access your data.

Answer (score 0):

I think Dezso is right. You do not need to use looping the array using an index.
If you make a select statement grouping by person_id in combination with limit 1, you have the result set you wanted:

```
create or replace function statement_example(p_data text[]) returns int as $$
declare
 rw event_log%rowtype;
begin
  for rw in select * from "PRD".events_log where (event_type_id = 100 or event_type_id = 101) and person_id = any(operators_id::int[]) and plc_time < begin_date_g order by plc_time desc group by person_id limit 1 loop
  raise notice 'interesting log: %', rw.field;
  end loop;
  return 1;
end;
$$ language plpgsql volatile;
```

That should perform much better.
If you still prefer looping an integer array and there are a lot of person_ids to look after, then might you consider using the flyweight design pattern:

```
create or replace function flyweight_example(p_data text[]) returns int as $$
declare
 i_id int;
 i_min int;
 i_max int;
begin
 i_min := array_lower(p_data,1);
 i_max := array_upper(p_data,1);
 for i_id in i_min .. i_max loop
  raise notice 'interesting log: %',p_data[i_id];
 end loop;
 return 1;
end;
$$ language plpgsql volatile;
```